# my cart value not store in cart session in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

- I am currently working on e commerce project. I am unable to create a
  session or store cart value in session below is the code snippet:
- Technology Used : Php Laravel 6

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Product;
  use Session;
  use Auth;
  class CartController extends Controller
  {
  public function addedtocart(Request $request){
  $id=$request->proid;
  $quantity=$request->quantity;
  $product = Product::find($id);
  $cart = $request->session()->get('cart');
  if(isset($cart[$product['Product_ID']])):
  $cart[$product['Product_ID']]['qty'] += $quantity;
  else:
  $cart[$product['Product_ID']] = $product;
  $cart[$product['Product_ID']]['qty'] = $quantity;
  endif;
  Session::push('cart',$cart);
  return view('frontend.cart.addedtocart',compact('product'));
  }
  }

Could you please anyone help to me?

Answer (score 0):

I only can recommend you https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart package
It will make your life easier!!!